# TypeError: put() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_sudo'

Tags: python, fabric

I run the following:

```
 c = Connection('sid', config=config) 
 c.put("local", "/etc/nginx/sites-available/addr", use_sudo=True)
```

I get

```
~/.virtualenvs/fabric/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fabric/connection.py in put(self, *args, **kwargs)
    784         .. versionadded:: 2.0
    785         """
--> 786         return Transfer(self).put(*args, **kwargs)
    787 
    788     # TODO: yield the socket for advanced users? Other advanced use cases

TypeError: put() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_sudo'
```

Can't I do this with fabric core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  `Connection.put` is [just a wrapper](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.put) around `Transfer.put`, and `Transfer.put` [only has three parameters](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/transfer.html#fabric.transfer.Transfer.put):  (1) `local`, (2) `remote` and (3) `preserve_mode`.